# Why are all bindings resolved every $digest cycle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, angularjs-scope

I stuck a break point on a bound function and found that it is being called every digest cycle.  I have a timer displaying a countdown on the page, and was not expecting the update of the timer value to also cause all other properties to be updated.

In the demo below, three instances of two controllers are evident.  Unexpectedly, the first two dates are updated every time the `$timer` is executes.  Even though the second date is in a different scope.

I can stop the date from being updated every time by preceding the binding with `::` as in the third date (which doesn't update), however, this doesn't scale well.  How can I instead cause the timer element to update, but not all other bindings?

**Demo**

http://plnkr.co/edit/1IhAabzBXMVl9LEfaf8M?p=preview

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.countDownLeft = 99999;
    vm.myFunction = function() { return new Date(); }

    function countdown() {
     vm.countDownLeft--;
     $timeout(countdown, 1000);
    }
    countdown();
}]).controller('SecondCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.myFunction = function() { return new Date(); }
});
```

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <p>Counter: {{vm.countDownLeft}}</p>
  <p>Updates: {{ vm.myFunction() }}</p>
</div>
<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl as vm2">
  <p>Updates: {{ vm2.myFunction() }}</p>
</div>
<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl as vm3">
  <p>Doesn't update: {{ ::vm3.myFunction() }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'doesn't scale well' related to using `::`? Also, you should probably be using `$interval` instead of `$timeout` here to simplify things.

Comment: Say I have *n* bindings and one timer.  I have to apply the :: to the *n* bindings (through multiple scopes) I don't want updated, rather than just stop the timer from causing the *n* bindings to update...

Comment: Also, I agree about `$interval`, but the outcome is the same.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your use case here yet, but if you're concerned about using `::`, couldn't you just initialize a $scope variable like `$scope.myDate = new Date()` so the date wouldn't change every digest cycle?

Comment: My concern is performance based.  Why should all bindings be resolved when only one is being updated?

Comment: Ah, in that case `::` should be your best bet, since it's a one-way binding, so angular stops `$watch`:ing it as soon as the variable following `::` gets a defined value. If it's something you're not going to update at any point, you'd definitely want to use `::`. EDIT: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html

Comment: So otherwise it is expected that the $digest cycle updates global bindings?

Comment: Yes, to my understanding, that's correct.

Comment: I suppose :: is your only option afaik. There is a third boolean parameter to $timeout which triggers $rootScope.$apply() (which in-turn triggers digest cylcle). By default it is true. You can set it to false but that would not update your counter variable in the scope.

Comment: @Bharat Yeah, I investigated the third parameter already.  My thinking is that it seems overkill that $digest affects global scope, rather than the currently modified scope, and that peppering the majority (in my case) of the bindings with `::` seems like code smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current workaround is to use jQuery to update the timer outside of the angular $digest cycle.  I don't like it, but there you go;

**Demo**

http://plnkr.co/edit/cjNUKpRhP10OxYIfbnFj?p=preview

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <p>Counter: <span id="countDownLeft"></span></p>
  <p>Updates: {{ vm.myFunction() }}</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function countdown() {
    vm.countDownLeft--;
    $("#countDownLeft").text(vm.countDownLeft);
    setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}
```